# Does instanceof return true if instance of a parent?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, instanceof

I have a class `Child` that extends `Parent`.

```
Parent child = new Child();

if (child instanceof Parent){
    // Do something
}
```

Does this return true or false, and why?

Comment: By just compiling and executing your code you would have got the answer, at least to the first question.

Comment: Of course. I think it was a rhetorical question as I was trying to make sense of type hierarchy in Java long time ago. I also wanted to invoke a good answer that could help the community.While it's obvious that Child is a subtype of Parent, it was questionable for me why it would also be an instance of it. To me it was only logical this to return true when it was the exact type. I would also expect a more explicit operator such as subtypeOf in that time

Answer (score 74, accepted):

[Yes](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/TheinstanceofKeyword.htm), it would. And why should it not?

Because child is in fact an instance of Parent. If, you want to perform an operation only for a child you should check

```
if (child instanceof Child){
}
```

However you should remember the following statement from Effective C++, by Scott Meyers :

> "Anytime you find yourself writing
> code of the form "if the object is of
> type T1, then do something, but if
> it's of type T2, then do something
> else," slap yourself.

which I think applies in this case too. If you want to *doSomething* based on what type of class the referenced object belongs to, the following code structure should help you with it.

**NOTE:** I have not compiled it.

```
class Parent {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("I am the Parent, and I do as I like");
    }
}
 
class ChildA extends Parent {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("I am a child named A, but I have my own ways, different from Parent");
    }
}
 
class ChildB extends Parent {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("I am a child named B, but I have my own ways, different from my Parent and my siblings");
    }
}
 
public class Polymorphism101 {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
        Parent p = new Parent();
        p.doSomething();
 
        p = new ChildA();
        p.doSomething();
 
        p = new ChildB();
        p.doSomething();
 
    }
 
}
```

**EDIT: A better example**

You could be developing a *drawing* application. An application that draws shapes of any kind. In that case, you should have an *abstract* type `Shape`.

For purpose(s) like; drawing all shapes; list all shapes; find a shape or delete a shape, you need to have a *list* of Shapes. Since the list is of a parent type, it can store any shapes.

The `Shape` *interface/abstract class/virtual class* should have an *abstract/pure virtual* function `Draw()`. So, in your DrawToDeviceLoop, you just call `Draw()` for each shape, you never need to check what shape it is.

The `Shape` interface can have an *abstract* implementation `AbstractShape`, which can have shape name or id as data members and GetName, Cleanup and other functions with functionality common to all shapes.

Remember an abstract type **cannot** be instantiated, so `Shape` itself cannot be instantiated, as it cannot be drawn either.

**EDIT 2: Polymorphism and Exception Handling** - [user1955934](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1955934) asked "What about checking for exception class" For exception handling the best practices with respect to polymorphism are:

1. Prefer (to throw) specific exception - For example throw a NumberFormatException instead of IllegalArgumentException
2. Catch the most specific exception first - For example, if you catch an IllegalArgumentException first, you will never reach the catch block that should handle the more specific NumberFormatException because it’s a subclass of the IllegalArgumentException.

So, its principally the same, if an exception needs to be handled differently, a child/specific class should be defined, and the specific exception should be *caught* (not checked instanceof)

To know more best practices on exception handling. See [9 Best practices to handle exception in Java](https://dzone.com/articles/9-best-practices-to-handle-exceptions-in-java) and [Best practices for exceptions (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions)

**EDIT 3: I admit to an exception in this rule**

So, I am working with a legacy code (written in C++), which has mostly been written about 15 years ago, where they always check for the child class to perform certain actions. I was asked to add some code with the same logic, and I told my manager (he is a Dev too) I cannot do this, pointing to this answer, and then we discussed and accepted to this exception to the rule. In our case, this parent class has had just 2 children since the year 2000, and we do not see any child being added in the near future, with the core code limited for growth, we decided that with no addition to child classes and current number being just 2, it is more efficient to check for type, especially when that is how the code has been written, since ever.

There aren't many instances of this check too though, the parent implements the complicated functionalities mostly and it exists more for sharing code then specializing/differentiating them.

Comment: but I determine the object type in runtime and I need to define a parent reference to hold all types of childs. how can I do that in the other way?

Comment: @user479129: You can hold a reference to any of a parent's child(s) in a reference of type parent. That is if there is a `class Parent {}` and `class ChildA extends Parent` and `class ChildB extends Parent` then you can use `Parent p` to refer an object of type `ChildA` or `ChildB`, but I don't get what you mean by other way round.

Comment: I need to control that object p is a type of its child, not the parent. in some cases it can be the parent type so I need to check that it is exactly the type I want. that is what I want. I hope it s clear

Comment: I would like an improved answer as well, this would be useful for working with Frame.getComponents() instead of handling each one individually.

Comment: @JasonK. Do you mean a better example?

Comment: what about checking for exception class?

Answer (score 7):

**instanceof** will return true if it's a subclass...

[**instanceof Documentation**](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Instructions2.doc6.html#instanceof)

Comment: And now, this question is always true. Thank

Answer (score 0):

ofcourse it returns true because child is an instance of the parent

Comment: Yes, java any return true if child is instance of the parent (or implement).

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**. `instanceof` will be true whenever the reference(left side of the `instanceof` expression) can be cast to the *ReferenceType*(the type on the right side of the `instanceof` expression). This will be true for subclasses in relation to their parent:

```
Child child = new Child();
Parent parent = (Parent) child; //works!
assert child instanceof Parent; //true
```

From [The Java Language Specification, Java SE 9 Edition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/index.html):

> [**15.20. Relational Operators**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20)
> ...
> *RelationalExpression* instanceof *ReferenceType*
>
> [**15.20.2. Type Comparison Operator instanceof**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2)
> ...
> At run time, the result of the `instanceof` operator is `true` if the value of the *RelationalExpression* is not `null` and the reference could be cast to the *ReferenceType* without raising a `ClassCastException`. Otherwise the result is `false`.