# Does the instanceof operator consider sibling classes instance-ofs?

Tags: java, class, instanceof

So, If I have four classes, A, B, C and D. Classes B and C extend class A and class D extends class C. Using Java's `instanceof` operator will `B instanceof C` return true because they have the same parent?

Comment: Would an instance of `B` be an instance of `C`? **No**. But `B` would be an instanceof `A` (as would `C`).

Comment: Think of `instanceof` as `childOf`. `A childOf B`? No. `B childOf A`? Yes. In other news, `instanceof` usually signals poor OO design.

Comment: If you formatted your question better you wouldn't've received the down vote.

Comment: You could have tested this out on your computer for yourself to see...

Comment: Showing your own research is a criterion for asking. [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. They are "siblings". Classes C and B are both instances of A, but they are not instances of each other.

the following tests are **true**

```
B instanceof A
C instanceof A
D instanceof C
```

Note that the following are **false**

```
A instanceof B
A instanceof C
C instanceof D
```

The child class is an instance of the parent, but not the opposite. That's because the parent doesn't know what are the new behaviors implemented by the child, but the child inherits all behaviors from the parent.

More info on this thread: [Does instanceof return true if instance of a parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304056/does-instanceof-returns-true-if-instance-of-a-parent)