# Check if subclass is instance of parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got the following three classes:

```
class MessageBuilder
   def initialize(template)
       @template = template
       puts @template.instance_of? MessengerTemplate 
   end
end

class MessengerTemplate
    def initialize
        @default_template_id = "111111"
    end
end

class JobTemplate < MessengerTemplate
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
        @template_id = "2222"
    end
end
```

I'm trying to check if a parameter passed to `MessageBuilder#initialize` is an instance of `MessengerTemplate`. If not, I need to throw an error.

When I call:

```
message = MessageBuilder.new(JobTemplate.new("Invoice"))
```

the following line in the constructor:

```
puts @template.instance_of? MessengerTemplate
```

prints `FALSE`.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried `@template.is_a?(MessengerTemplate)`?

Comment: @jvillian your suggestion does return `True`. Isn't `JobTemplate` technically an instance of `MessengerTemplate`? I know if I did this in `Java` the `instanceOf` method would have passed as indicated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304056/does-instanceof-return-true-if-instance-of-a-parent

Comment: Nope. `JobTemplate` is a *subclass* of `MessengerTemplate`. @template is an *instance* of `JobTemplate`. Please see answer for details. I don't know nothing about no Java.

Comment: I suspect you wish to correct the line `puts @template.instance_of? MessengerTemplate` so that it returns `true` if `@template` is an instance of `MessengerTemplate` or a subclass of `MessengerTemplate`. If so, please correct the statement of the problem.

Comment: You have awarded the greenie to an answer that conforms with the interpretation I gave in my comment above. However, you state, "I'm trying to check if a parameter passed to MessageBuilder#initialize is an instance of MessengerTemplate". That is incorrect and needs to be corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
@template.is_a?(MessengerTemplate)
```

As noted in the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F):

> Returns true if *class* is the class of *obj*, or if *class* is one of the superclasses of *obj* or modules included in *obj*.

`MessengerTemplate` is a superclass of `@template`, therefore `@template.is_a?(MessengerTemplate) => true`.

Comment: ...or `@template.class <= MessengerTemplate` or `MessengerTemplate === @template` . See See [Module#<=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-3C-3D) and [Module#===](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D).

Comment: @CarySwoveland exactly. Strictly speaking, `Module#<=` is the **only** way to check for requested _“is an instance of MessengerTemplate”_. `is_a?` will apparently return `true` for _modules_.